# How to delete file after I finished using it?

Tags: python, windows, moviepy

I am trying to remove files after I'm done using them but I get an error all the time...

The error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '0.mp4'

I tried closing the Objects but Its not working...

```
import os
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 720
DEFAULT_WIDTH = 1280

clip_names = ["0.mp4", "1.mp4"]

clips = []
for name in clip_names:
    clips.append(VideoFileClip(name).resize(width=DEFAULT_WIDTH,height=DEFAULT_HEIGHT))

final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips)
final_clip.write_videofile("video.mp4")

for clip in clips:
    clip.__del__()

for name in clip_names:
    os.remove(name)
```

I want to remove the file with os.remove...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: your os.remove(name) should be inside the for statment.

Comment: Fix the indentation too

Comment: The error: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: '0.mp4'

Comment: `[WinError 32]` means you are using Windows. Which version? Did you look with Performance Monitor on open file handles? Which processes locks your files?

Comment: The error message for `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` (32) is misleading. A file's read, write, and delete open count and share count are tracked by the file system. It's not related to processes. We can get a sharing violation with a second open on a file in the same process. Also, shared data access for a file is not file locking, which works on regions of a file. Python opens files with read and write sharing, but not delete sharing. Deleting a file requires opening it with delete access, which will fail as long as at least one existing open with data access does not share delete access.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try simply closing the clips?

```
for clip in clips:
    clip.close()
```

From the source [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/io/VideoFileClip.py#L71).

Or, if you want to do this cleanly in case of errors, use a `with` context:

```
import contextlib

with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    clips = []
    for name in clip_names:
        clip = VideoFileClip(name)
        stack.enter_context(contextlib.closing(clip))
        clips.append(clip.resize(width=DEFAULT_WIDTH,height=DEFAULT_HEIGHT))

    final_clip = concatenate_videoclips(clips)
    final_clip.write_videofile("video.mp4")

# exiting the `with` block released the clips
for name in clip_names:
    os.remove(name)
```

This approach uses an [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) to track clips. When the program exits the `with` block, all contexts passed to `enter_context` are exited, releasing all the clips.

Comment: .close(), is not an option anymore. (AttributeError: 'VideoFileClip' object has no attribute 'close')

Comment: hmmm, are you using an old version maybe? close was added in latest version, from file history.

Comment: There is an issue on github about the addition of `.close()` : https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/596 — TLDR you have to upgrade to latest version to get the `.close()` method, otherwise you won't be able to close the clip at all.

Comment: I'm using '0.2.3.2', I think its the last version... I checked the docs and I didn't find a close() function.

Comment: Latest version is [0.2.3.5](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/releases). First version with a `.close()` is 0.2.3.3, you were unlucky on that one ;)

Comment: Do note however that there are still [open issues](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/745) on the issue tracker of the project, where `.close()` sometimes fails to release everything. But that's your best bet at this point.

Comment: yep, I was wrong. I had a requirement from another lib and that didn't let me downloading the lastest version. thanks...

Comment: But the error is still showing up... I think its because of the "resize" function...

Comment: Possibly. As I wrote, there are some issues open on the project's tracker with people calling `close()` but `close()` failing to free the resources. It's apparently a known bug.

Comment: You might want to add yourself to [this issue](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/681) which seems related. Or open a new issue describing the problem (with the `.close()` version) and hopefully they can find the bug.